# Firebase Cloud function: Weird timestamp bug

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have implemented Stories in my Flutter+Firebase app, and wrote a Cloud Function in JS to delete all stories older than 24h. I added a test Story in the Database, with a field 'timestamp' and set it to August 25, 8:00. Now when I am running the function, I print out the document id and the timestamp of that found document. However, the dates that get printed out are all in 1973!?

Here is my function:

```js
// Start delete old Stories
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '512MB'
}
const MAX_CONCURRENT = 3;
const PromisePool = promisePool.PromisePool;
exports.storiesCleanup = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun( 
  async context => {
    console.log('Cleaning stories...');
    await getOldStories();
    //const promisePool = new PromisePool(() => deleteOldStories(oldStories), MAX_CONCURRENT);
    //await promisePool.start();
    console.log("finished cleaning stories");
  }
);

async function getOldStories() {
    const yesterday = Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000;
    console.log("Yesterday: " + yesterday);
    
    var storyPostsRef = admin.firestore().collection("StoryPosts");
    var query = storyPostsRef.where("timestamp", "<", yesterday);

    storyPostsRef.get().then(
      querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(
          (doc) => {
            // HERE I AM PRINTING OUT!
            console.log("Found document: " + doc.id + ", which was created on: " + doc.data().timestamp);
            //doc.ref.delete();
          }
        )
        return null;
      }
    ).catch(error => {throw error;});
}
//End delete old stories
```

Here is a picture of a document and its timestamp:
[image]

And this is a picture of the id and timestamp printed out for that document:
[image]

Edit: So for printing out, I figured that if I print `doc.data().timestamp.seconds` I get the correct number of seconds since epoch. But I still don't understand what the number 06373393200.000000 (printed in the picture above) is. And how do I then make a query when I want to get all stories where the timestamp is small than today-24h ?

`var query = storyPostsRef.where("timestamp", "<", Timesstamp.fromDate(yesterday));` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you come to the conclusion that the printed timestamp is from a year other than the one shown in the console, then you are misinterpreting the output.  Firestore timestamps are represented with two values - an offset in **seconds** since the unix epoch, and another offset in nanoseconds from that time.  This much is evident from the API documentation for [Timestamp](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html).

You're probably taking the **seconds** offset value and interpreting as an offset in **milliseconds**, which is common in other timestamp systems.  You can see how this would cause problems.  If you want to take that a Firestore offset in seconds and use a tool to interpret it in a system that uses milliseconds, you will need to first multiply that value by 1,000,000 to convert seconds to milliseconds.

Comment: I was aware of the format of the timestamp, but I still don't understand what the number is that gets printed out. When I print do.data().timestampt.seconds then the number is in fact the number of seconds after Epoch. So now I wonder how can I strucutre the query where I ask: "where('timestamp' '<', yesterday) ? How can I bring yesterday in the same format the timestamp is in?

Comment: If you have another question about using timestamps in queries, please post that separately. Stack Overflow is only intended to deal with one question at a time.